# Use of Between operator in the context of varchar values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

In an sql where condition there is a value like below

```
select * from tabl
where
code not between 'A00' and 'B99'
```

how does this work? till now i was thinking it works only with numeric and date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BETWEEN operator will treat these as varchars, and apply its comparison rules accordingly:

BETWEEN returns TRUE if the value of test_expression is greater than or equal to the value of begin_expression and less than or equal to the value of end_expression.

> SQL uses a list of the ASCII codes to determine which to sort where
>   and in what order.

Comment: can you explain for the example mentioned

Comment: you mean to say that this does not include A01,A02...UPTO B98?

Comment: It's Just Work with ASCII Values

Comment: SQL uses a list of the ASCII codes to determine which to sort where and in what order.

Comment: so in this               select * from tabl
where
code not between 'A00' and 'B99'               can you tell me how does that work..does it exclude A01,A02...UPTO B98?

Comment: @user1254579 It won't include A01,A02...UPTO B98

Comment: @user1254579 Even you get That's because just 9 is less than 0. so it may include but is' not exact operation

Answer (score 1):

The same way as `ORDER BY` works on `varchar` values.

Every `char` has its `ASCII` code and sort order, so every value can be compared by its `ASCII` code.

Comment: So in this context,you mean to say that this does not include A01,A02...UPTO B98?